# how do I optmize the weights of the input layer using backward for this simple neural network in pytorch when .grad is None

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent

I defined the following simple neural network:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

X = torch.tensor(([1, 2]), dtype=torch.float)
y = torch.tensor([1.])
learning_rate = 0.001

class Neural_Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Neural_Network, self).__init__()
        
        self.W1 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(([1, 0], [2, 3]), dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True))
        self.W2 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(([2], [1]), dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True))
        
    def forward(self, X):
        self.xW1 = torch.matmul(X, self.W1)
        self.h = torch.tensor([torch.tanh(self.xW1[0]), torch.tanh(self.xW1[1])])
        return torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(self.h, self.W2))
        
net = Neural_Network() 

for z in range(60):
    loss = (y - net(X))**2
    optim = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)
    loss = criterion(net(X), y)
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

I can run it and `print(net.W1) print(net.W2)` prints

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[1., 0.],
        [2., 3.]], requires_grad=True)
Parameter containing:
tensor([[2.0078],
        [1.0078]], requires_grad=True)
```

So my problem is that it seems like `W1` is not being updated.
When I call `print(net.W1.grad)` I get `None` for every iteration which confuses me a lot.

- I tried to define the function as one line like so:
  `loss = (y - torch.sigmoid(math.tanh(x[0] * W_1[0][0] + x[1] * W_1[1][0]) * W_2[0] + math.tanh(x[0] * W_1[0][1] + x[1] * W_1[1][1]) * W_2[1])) ** 2`, but it did not help anything.
- For sure I could hardcode the derivate and everything but it seems painful and I though `.backward()` can be used in this case.

How can I optmize `W1` with using `backward()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the following line:

`self.h = torch.tensor([torch.tanh(self.xW1[0]), torch.tanh(self.xW1[1])])`

is the culprit.

The new tensor `self.h` does not inherit the `requires_grad` attribute from `self.xW1` and, by default, it is set to `False`.

You can call `self.h = self.tanh(self.xW1)` and the operation will be then applied point-wise to all the elements of `self.xW1`.

In addition, I suggest you to inspect your gradients by using [PyTorch hooks](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.register_hook.html).

Comment: thanks! this worked fine, I only had to use `torch.tanh(self.xW1)` instead of `self.tanh(..)`, what is the benefit of using hooks here, I don't know how to use them

Comment: The gradient tensor of intermediate of non-leaf nodes in the DAG is deleted as soon as it is not needed anymore, so it is safer to use hooks like `W.register_hook(print)` which will print the gradient as soon it is computed. Have a look at [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html) for more info.

In your case, since  `W_1` and `W_2` are leaf nodes of the DAG, printing is ok. Mine was just a suggestion for future, more complex, debugging :)